# Test individual RAM performance

Tags: windows, windows-7, performance-analysis

I have installed a new RAM in my laptop and want to compare performance of individual RAM's. Is there any tool that allows me to test speed of individual RAM's.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/):

- free
- Bootable program (so that it can fully test the RAM without being annoyed having some OS in RAM at the same time)

[image]

Note that if you have 1 RAM at 1333 and 1 RAM at 1600,  it would just run at 1333:  RAM will always run at the speed of the slowest stick. Same for the latency: the highest latency will be used by both RAM sticks. As a result the only way to compare individual RAM is to manually add/remove them from your computer and run a speed test on each of them.

Comment: Too bad for me. I can't open RAM myself from my laptop :( Anyway, thanks for answer

Comment: @VarunAgw How did you install the new RAM if you can't access it with your laptop?

Comment: @Overv The shop owner where I purchased the RAM did the whole work.